# How to evaluate the following interesting integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Show that the integral,

$$\frac{3}{x^3}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^3}{e^t-1}=\frac{\pi^4}{5x^3}+ O(e^{-x}) $$  for $x>>1$

I tried ignoring the one in the denominator and then trying by parts but it gets too long and is maybe wrong.

Also, tried approximating the upper limit as infinity but that doesn't help and is probably wrong.

Comment: The integrand equals $t^3e^{-t} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nt}$.   Now consider incomplete $\Gamma$ functions.

Comment: Ya. I had reached this step. So here, taking the integral inside and summation inside gives a really really big mess in functions of n. I tried checking the integral online and that gives the same big mess.

Comment: I assume when you say incomplete gamma u simply mean to integrate with x as upper limit

Comment: Write the integral as $\int\limits_0^\infty-\int\limits_x^\infty$. The first is exactly a Zeta times Gamma, and you just need to study the second for large $x$

Answer (score 1):

Note as Hans spotted we have $$\frac{t^3e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}} = t^3e^{-t}(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}e^{-nt}) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}t^3e^{-jt}$$

whenever $t > 0$.

By integration by parts (no I totally didn't use wolfram alpha)

$$\int_{a}^{x}t^3e^{-jt}dt = \frac{e^{-aj} (a^3 j^3 + 3 a^2 j^2 + 6 a j + 6)}{j^4} - \frac{e^{-j x} (j^3 x^3 + 3 j^2 x^2 + 6 j x + 6)}{j^4}$$

Now whenever $0<a<x$ we have

$$\int_{a}^{x}\frac{t^3e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}} dt= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{-aj} (a^3 j^3 + 3 a^2 j^2 + 6 a j + 6)}{j^4} - \frac{e^{-j x} (j^3 x^3 + 3 j^2 x^2 + 6 j x + 6)}{j^4}\right)$$

Now set $b > 0$

we have

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj} (b^3 j^3 + 3 b^2 j^2 + 6 b j + 6)}{j^4} = b^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj}}{j}+3b^2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj}}{j^2}+6b\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj}}{j^3}+6\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj}}{j^4}$$

Now note

$$b^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj}}{j} = -b^3 \log(1-e^{-b}) \rightarrow 0$$

as $b \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

$$3b^2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj}}{j^2} \leq 3b^2 \zeta(2) \rightarrow 0$$

as $b \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

$$6b\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj}}{j^3} \leq 6b\zeta(3) \rightarrow 0$$

as $b \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

$$6\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bj}}{j^4} \rightarrow 6\zeta(4)$$

as $b \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

Thus

$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^3e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}} dt = \lim_{a \rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{a}^{x}\frac{t^3e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}} dx  = 6\zeta(4)-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-j x} (j^3 x^3 + 3 j^2 x^2 + 6 j x + 6)}{j^4}$$

Thus for $x > 1$ we have

$$|\int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^3e^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}} dt-6\zeta(4)| \leq 18x^3\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}e^{-jx} = 18x^3\frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} \leq \frac{18}{1-e^{-1}}e^{-x}x^{3}$$

This proves your result when we multiply both sides by $\frac{3}{x^3}$ and use $\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$.

Comment: Just as a note: the integration of integrands like $t^3e^{-x}$ are quite easily done by another form of by-parts, called tabular integration. An example can be seen [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/tabular-integration).